# How to delete table created after Optimize Table crashed in MySQL

Tags: mysql, percona

On a Percona 5.6.19 server, I tried to run an OPTIMIZE on a table:

`mysql> optimize table mydb.mytable;`

The Optimize runs correctly but stop because of a space issues...

So now, when I want to run it again:

```
+------------------------------+----------+----------+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Table | Op | Msg_type | Msg_text |
+------------------------------+----------+----------+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
| mydb.mytable | optimize | note | Table does not support optimize, doing recreate + analyze instead |
| mydb.mytable | optimize | error | Table 'mydb/#sql-ib1676944' already exists |
| mydb.mytable | optimize | status | Operation failed |
+------------------------------+----------+----------+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

So, I tried to delete this temporary table:

`mysql> use mydb`

`mysql> DROP TABLE`#mysql50##sql-ib1676944`;`

but I got this message:

> ERROR 1051 (42S02): Unknown table 'mydb.#mysql50##sql-ib1676944'

If I search for it:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.INNODB_SYS_TABLES WHERE NAME LIKE '%#sql%';

+----------+------------------------+------+--------+---------+-------------+------------+---------------+
| TABLE_ID | NAME | FLAG | N_COLS | SPACE | FILE_FORMAT | ROW_FORMAT | ZIP_PAGE_SIZE |
+----------+------------------------+------+--------+---------+-------------+------------+---------------+
| 1693810 | mydb/#sql-ib1676944 | 1 | 6 | 1693796 | Antelope | Compact | 0 |
+----------+------------------------+------+--------+---------+-------------+------------+---------------+
```

I have no idea how to delete this table anyone can help?

regards

PS: I used this https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7...-datadict.html